# C++ possible for UI development on Android and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, user-interface, cross-platform

I wanted to know if it's possible to write mobile apps in C++.
On the Internet I found just article for writing apps in Kotlin, or FLutter/Dart.
I found some sites where I can read something about C++ and apps, but this sites are 3 - 5 years old.
Is it possible or do I a seperate framework like QT for C++ to do this?

Best regards
Ben

Comment: Qt is a C++ framework, so why are you asking if it is possible to use C++ for mobile app development if Qt can be used for mobile app development?

Comment: Even if there is, it is not recommended to use, there may be many bugs waiting for you. I guess you only know C++ at present, but you want to do iOS and Android. Then you can consider cross-platform solutions such as Flutter, RN, etc. The only cost is that you need to learn a new language, which is better than solving unknown bugs in C++. But a cross-platform solution is not a panacea. When you need some special functions, you have to use Native to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Qt, Unity, Microsoft Visual Studio all have the option to use c++ and have versions optimised for mobile. One of these tools should be able to make mobile development relatively easy for you.

There are heaps more that work as well though those ones are some of the most well known frameworks and programs that do it.